# Problem with storage ionic and angular, return undefined data used service

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Use this service but return undefined data.

```
  // Function for get a element to the store
  public async get(name: string): Promise<any> {
    await this._storage?.get(name);
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you created the _storage var with `storage.create()`, where `storage:Storage`?

`storage.create()` return a Promise, so before call get or set you have to wait that your storage is created/loaded.

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage-angular';

export class DBService {
    private _storage: Storage = null;
    constructor(private storage: Storage) {}
    
    async init() {
        this._storage = await this.storage.create();
    }

    async get(key: string) {
        if(!this._storage)
            await this.init() ;
        return await this._storage?.get(key) ;
    }
    async set(key: string, data: any) {
        if(!this._storage)
            await this.init() ;
        return await this._storage?.set(key, data) ;
    }
}
```